# Extract gurobi muti-dimensional variable value and form a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gurobi

I want to know that when I defined a multi-dimension variables in Gurobi, how can I extract all the value of the solution and organize them in to a Numpy array according to the original coordinate of the variable.

I have the following decision variables defined in Gurobi using Python API:

```
for i in range(N):
  for t in range(M):
      Station_Size[i,t] = m.addVar(ub=Q, name = 'Station_Size_%s_%s' %(i,t))
      for j in range(N):
         Admission[i,j,t] = m.addVar(ub = Arrival_Rate[t,i,j], obj=-1, name = 'Admission_Rate_%s_%s_%s' %(i,j,t))
         Return[i,j,t] = m.addVar(name = 'Return_Rate_%s_%s_%s' %(i,j,t))
```

I have the problem solved and I have three dictionary:

```
Station_Size, Admission and Return
```

I know that the solution can be accessed as:

```
Station_Size[i,t].X, Admission[i,j,t].X and Return[i,j,t].X
```

I want to creat three Numpy array such that:

```
Array_Station_Size[i,t] = Station_Size[i,t].X
Array_Admission[i,j,t] = Admission[i,j,t].X
```

I can definitely do this by creating three loops and creat the Numpy Array element by element. It's do-able if the loop doesn't take a lot of time. But I just want to know if there is a better way to do this. Please comment if  I did not make myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model's name is `m`, do the following:

```
Array_Station_Size = m.getAttr('x', Station_Size)
```

which is a gurobipy.tupledict now.
see gurobi doc here
http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_windows/py_results.html

Comment: This is way better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured this problem out.

Do the following:

```
Array_Station_Size = np.array()
Array_Station_Size[i,] = [Station_Size[i,t].X for t in rang(T)]
```

Comment: Let me know if you have a better way to do this.